# Laravel 5.1 Query Scope

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, scope

this is my scope code:

```
public function scopeTest($query, $text, $usrId)
{
    if (trim($text) != "") {
        return $query->where("usrid", "=" ,"$usrId")->where("text1", "LIKE" ,"%$text%")->orWhere("text2", "LIKE" ,"%$text%");
    }else{
        return $query->where("usrid", "=" ,"$usrId");
    }
}
```

I cant building this query:

```
select * from table where usrid = $usrId and (text1 like '%$text%' or text2 like '%$text%');
```

Because the "or" condition doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Use a closure to create a group](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses):

```php
$query->where('usrid', $usrId)->where(function ($query) use ($text) {
   $like = "%{$text}%";

   $query->where('text1', 'LIKE', $like)->orWhere('text2', 'LIKE' ,$like); 
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to introduce the `$text` variable to the scope.

Comment: Although it is your post, I didn't find a convincing reason for your last edit. I found it offensive at the time and voted down.